# Let $f,g \in AC[a,b]$. Show that $\int_a^b fg' = f(b)g(b) -f(a)g(a) - \int_a^b f'g$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

Let $f,g \in AC[a,b]$. Show that $\int_a^b fg' = f(b)g(b) -f(a)g(a) - \int_a^b f'g$.

Will integration by parts be useful here? I believe the first part of this problem is showing that $f'g$ and $fg'$ are integrable; to that end, here is hat I've got so far:

$proof:$________________________

Since $f,g \in AC[a,b]$, $f$ and $g$ are bounded by $N,M$ respectively.

Thus $\int_a^b fg' \leq N \int_a^b g'=N (g(b)-g(a)) < \infty$

and $\int_a^b f'g \leq M \int_a^b g'=M (f(b)-f(a)) < \infty$

Thus $fg'$ and $gf'$ are integrable.

Now, as far as showing that  $\int_a^b fg' = f(b)g(b) -f(a)g(a) - \int_a^b f'g$, I feel like I need to use integration by parts somehow but I'm not sure.... So far, i've just wrote

$\int_a^b \frac{d}{dx} (fg) = \int_a^b f'g + g'f = \int_a^b f'g + \int_a^b fg'$... Looking for some insights, thanks!

Comment: What does AC mean?

Comment: "Will integration by parts be useful here?" This question basically asks you to prove that IBP works.

Comment: @Arthur Absolutely Continuous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is that, $fg$ is also AC, and $\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b}(fg)'=(fg)(b)-(fg)(a)$, can you finish the rest?

\begin{align*}
\int_{a}^{b}(fg)'=\int_{a}^{b}f'g+fg'=\int_{a}^{b}f'g+\int_{a}^{b}fg'.
\end{align*}

Comment: Do I just evaluate $(fg)'$ inside the integral, then use additivity of the integral along with my proof that $fg'$ and $gf'$ are integrable?